# calling a post api from another post api is not working in wso2 when the 2 apis are in the same server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have created two rest apis using wso2 6.1.1, the first one is calling the second one.
however the call of the second api is not working and keep throwing an error on the console that said:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /transfer_money/trans URL
 and    EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address http://10.5.222.192:8282/updateAccountAmmount will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed.

Note that when invoking the second api from postman, it works fine.
the code is below:

the first Api:

```
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{
                            "accountId":$1,
                            "ammount":$ctx:finalAmount
                        }</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.accountTo"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="message" value="start calling api full logs"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http format="rest" method="POST" uri-template="http://10.5.222.192:8282/updateAccountAmmount"/>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="message" value="result"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

The second API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/updateAccountAmmount" name="updateAccountAmmount" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="message" value="enter to the transfer of the money process"/>
            </log>
            <property expression="json-eval($.ammount)" name="ammount" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.accountId)" name="accountId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <dbreport>
                <connection>
                    <pool>
                        <password>root</password>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/trainingdb</url>
                        <user>root</user>
                    </pool>
                </connection>
                <statement>
                    <sql><![CDATA[UPDATE accounts SET ammount = ? where accountId = ?]]></sql>
                    <parameter expression="get-property('ammount')" type="CHAR"/>
                    <parameter expression="get-property('accountId')" type="CHAR"/>
                </statement>
            </dbreport>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Can you please advise what is the problem and how to solve it?